# Capture Table Changes Without Pressing Enter (DataGridView)

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I have been Googling and Binging all morning trying to find this answer.

I have a DataGridView that is bound to my SQL database using string builders. I have an update button on my form a user clicks to commit their new changes to the database. However, sometimes, I forget to press "Enter" to activate the event that tells the datagridview there are new changes on the data table. **Is there a way to not have to press enter to identify changes? Perhaps in the cellvalidating event?**

Comment: The `CellValidating` event might work. There is also a `CellValueChanged` event.

Comment: I am using both of those events for other functions. Is there a special line of code i need to tell the table there are new changes?

Comment: You could also just call your save routine and save the changes in the `CellValidated` event if you wanted to.

Comment: I don't want changes automatically sent to the db from the cellvalidated event. I want to have to push my update button. What i am looking for here, is the event that tells my datatable there are changes to the grid without pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the input string (before pressing Enter).

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());

        dgv.Rows.Add("text");

        dgv.EditingControlShowing += (sender, args) =>
                                     {
                                         Debug.Print(((DataGridView)sender).CurrentRow.Index.ToString());

                                         dgv.EditingControl.TextChanged -= EditingControlOnTextChanged;

                                         dgv.EditingControl.TextChanged += EditingControlOnTextChanged;
                                     };
    }

    private void EditingControlOnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Debug.Print(((TextBox) sender).Text);
    }
```